# How to make a virtual audio channel with PulseAudio on Mac OS?

Tags: audio, homebrew

I'm running Mac OS Monterey

I'd like to make a virtual audio channel to connect the audio output of one app to the audio input of another app.
On linux I'd use pulseaudio.  I installed pulseaudio from brew on my mac and attempted:

`pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual_Sink sink_properties=device.description=Virtual_Sink`

Pulse audio then will list it with `pacmd list-sinks`

but my apps do not see the channel.  The apps in question are gqrx and wsjtx.

I must be missing something... How is this supposed to work?

Comment: You'll probably find Mac users are far more likely to be using BlackHole, perhaps still SoundFlower which was the giant's shoulder the rest stand on, or something commercial from Rogue Amoeba.